# Calendar Control C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am trying to find a way that i can allow users to only click on specific number of weeks from current week. I have the calendar control set to SelectionMode="Dayweek" and they are not able to select a specific date, but i can not figure out how to prevent them from selecting any weeks other than those i want to allow them to select. This is for an employee scheduling application and we don't want to allow them to schedule more than three weeks in advance.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

    //dont allow select single day
    if (e.Day.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(21))
    {

        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }

    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
}

<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" SelectWeekText="Edit"  SelectionMode="Dayweek" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" ShowNextPrevMonth="true"  CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px">
    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
    <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />                        
</asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: wpf or winforms?

Comment: winform i believe

Comment: You believe? I see `asp` in your code... I don't think you're using winforms... Webforms maybe, not winforms. @user9285072's comment was posted before you edited that part of code in, because it's neither. If it truly is an ASP.NET project, you could add that tag.

Comment: Well its an asp page with C# code behind, forgive me for not being sure of the correct term in which i am working with.

Comment: I am to assume that no one knows how to resolve the issue i am having?